# Add Method to Class AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

https://github.com/vennemp/cdk-nwfirewall

look at src/index.tx

I have published an npm package for AWS CDK to deploy AWS Network Firewall.  It works great but I am currently expanding functionality and squashing bugs.   I am new to JS/TS so please excuse the spaghetti code.

My Class is FirewallStack and in that it creates a vpc - line 62.

When I create the FirewallStack, I want to be able to reference the subnets created in the vpc, like maybe even group them together - so if I want to launch a load balancer in the public subnets, I can just call the firewall stack and have amethod to grab the public subnets and pass that to my load balancer.

I've looked at other example of people creating methods and it is not working.

Have tried:

```
public listPublicSubnets (): FirewallStack {
   vpc.SubnetSelection(TYPE=PUBLIC)
}
```

################

```
public listPublicSubnet(): FirewallStack {
    return publicSubnets
}
```

Comment: What about it isn't working, are you getting a syntax error? Something at runtime?

Comment: My IDE (VScode) doesn't even recognize either of those variables, I'm not able to call them in a public method.

Comment: src/index.ts:550:31 - error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

550   public listPublicSubnets(): FirewallStack {
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/index.ts:551:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'vpc'.

551     vpc.publicSubnets
        ~~~
 Task "build » compile" failed when executing "jsii --silence-warnings=reserved-word --no-fix-peer-dependencies"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is stated to return a value of the type `FirewallStack`, but what you actually want to do is return the subnets, which have the type `ISubnet[]`.

This should do it:

```
public listPublicSubnets(): ISubnet[] {
   return vpc.publicSubnets
}
```

Edit: Looking at your code on GitHub, having this method on your class also assumes that you've added the vpc as an attribute in your class. You can do that by adding `private vpc: IVpc` to your `FirewallStack` class, and on line 62, you can set the attribute via `vpc = new ec2.Vpc(...)` instead of assigning the vpc to a local variable as you do now.

Comment: Thank you! I am desperately lost but this makes sense to me!

Comment: Thanks to your recommendation, I am getting somewhere.  Now I am running into a problem.  I am now able to use the listPublicSubnets method (not sure if it does what i want yet but I will fix that).  But since I instantiate vpc differently -- private vpc: IVpc; I am not longer able to get the internetgatewayid.  before vpc was set to Vpc (construct) which had the member to get the internetgatewayid.  I need to be able to get the internetgatewayid (line 91) when I add the properties to my vpc on line 62.  Or translate between IVpc and and Vpc.

Comment: This works if you set the attribute to be of type Vpc too!: `private vpc: Vpc`
If this answered your question it would be nice if you accepted the answer :)

Comment: I thought I tried that.  Omg it works.  I love you.